# glazed lists - default sorting?

Tags: java, glazedlists

I'm working with the Glazed List tutorial found [here](https://docs.google.com/Doc?id=dc5md22b_0g456kwd8) and [here](http://www.glazedlists.com/documentation/tutorial), but the implication is that you need a comparator to sort rows. However, I can't seem to figure out how to add support for sorting based on table header clicks.

Comment: are you using autocreaterowsorter on the JTable?

Comment: no, I don't know what that is. Can you explain?

Answer (score 1):

After more trial and error, I've found what I was doing wrong.

The `EventTableModel` **must** be instantiated with the `SortedList` instance, not the `EventList`. From the example:

```
private EventList<Issue> issuesEventList = new BasicEventList<Issue>();
...

        SortedList<Issue> sortedIssues = new SortedList<Issue>(issuesEventList, null);

        // create a panel with a table
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        // be careful not to put issuesEventList in here, it has to be the sortedIssues list
        EventTableModel<Issue> issuesTableModel = new EventTableModel<Issue>(sortedIssues, new IssueTableFormat());
```